# How can I remove Starting and ending double quotes from a markers string

Tags: javascript

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "MapImages.aspx/GetCctvData",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            var markers = '';
            var c = 0;
                 for (var j = 0; j < data.d.length; j++) {
                     markers = markers + '{'+
                        ' "title":'+'"'+ data.d[j].Name+'"'+','+ '"lat":'+'"'+data.d[j].Lat +'"'+','+' "lng":'+'"'+data.d[j].Lng +'"'+','+
                         '"img":' +'"'+ data.d[j].Url +'"'+ '}';

                     {
                     if(c!=97)
                         markers = markers +',';
                     }
                     c++;
                 }
                 markers= '[' + markers + ']';


        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(data.d[i].Name);
        }
    });



</script>
```

The output of markers consists such as:

```
  "[{ 
"title":"Simpang Pulai KM285.2",
"lat":"4.5425", "lng":"101.141",
"img":"http://plus.aviven.net/push/images/cctv/c3781ad96bde24b6a588c875ec58a57c.jpg"
}]"
```

Required output is:

```
  [{ 
"title":"Simpang Pulai KM285.2",
"lat":"4.5425", "lng":"101.141",
"img":"http://plus.aviven.net/push/images/cctv/c3781ad96bde24b6a588c875ec58a57c.jpg"
}]
```

Comment: Do you need `markers` to be string? A string value will always have surrounding `""`.

Comment: Wow! Where did you see that output?

Answer (score 0):

The type of `markers` is string, that's why you are getting `""` surrounding the object. Your required output looks like a json array. If you want `markers` to be a json array then make it an array like below:

```
var markers = [];
for (var j = 0; j < data.d.length; j++) {
    var marker = {
        title: data.d[j].Name,
        lat: data.d[j].Lat,
        lng: data.d[j].Lng,
        img: data.d[j].Url
    };
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with Toma.Never try to append the json string.When you need it,try to get it from the object, and will be more beautiful and clear and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the returned data from server. 
using:

```
$.parseJSON()
```

Example:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: Yes,I got the answer.